Unbox Error for override property in Swift?
import Foundation

enum OperationError: Error {
    case ioError(_ message: String)

    var localizedDescription: String {
        switch self {
        case .ioError(let message):
            return message
        }
    }
}

func test1() throws {
    throw OperationError.ioError("io error")
}

do {
    try test1()
} catch {
    print("\(error) type: \(type(of: error))")
    print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
    print("\((error as? OperationError)?.localizedDescription ?? "")")
}

Output:
ioError("io error") type: OperationError
The operation couldn’t be completed. (SwiftErrorDemo.OperationError error 0.)
io error

It seems the custom error couldn't be invoked to the correct property, I know the localizedDescription property is from Foundation framework, but for real type of the error is OperationError, why does the override localizedDescription get called?

"I know the localizedDescription property is from Foundation framework" Yes, that's exactly why you can't "override" it. It's a property declared in an extension, not a requirement of Error. Possible duplicate.

@Sweeper I thought it should be followed the local first principle to find my custom localizedDescription property because its type is my custom error OperationError.

That doesn't apply here because error is of type Error at compile time. The compiler can only resolve the property access to the built-in localizedDescription.

If you want to supply your own localizedDescription, adopt LocalizedError.
enum OperationError: LocalizedError {
    case ioError(_ message: String)

    var errorDescription: String? {
        switch self {
        case .ioError(let message): message
        }
    }
}

Your test code stays the same:
func test1() throws {
    throw OperationError.ioError("io error")
}

do {
    try test1()
} catch {
    print("\(error) type: \(type(of: error))")
    print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
    print("\((error as? OperationError)?.localizedDescription ?? "")")
}

Output from your test code:
ioError("io error") type: OperationError
io error
io error


@Itachi Don't change your catch block. You should still print localizedDescription.

@Sweeper But the localizedDescription only comes from Foundation.framework, errorDescription is from Swift.Misc. Could you please show me a guide or link for that? I found this thread.

@Itachi Umm... why is that a problem? What guide/link do you want? SE-0112 perhaps? This is the proposal that introduced LocalizedError.
